# Similarity and Scale Factor

Tags: geometry

If I have two triangles ABC and ADE and I know that each of the triangles is equilateral, each of the angles is 60 degrees. Is there a way to determine the scale factor of the two triangles, for example:

The ratio:

Area of ADE $:$Area of ABC

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: If the ratio of corresponding lengths in two similar figures is $p:q$, then the ratio of their areas is $p^2:q^2$. (The ratio of their volumes would be $p^3:q^3$.)

Comment: Yeah, I understand that Area of ADE $:$ Area of ABC $=$ $k^{2}$, where k is the scale factor.

Comment: Usually I am used to finding scale factor by dividing two sides but since no sides are given, I'm not sure how to find it.

Comment: Is there a figure? Without information beyond "each of the triangles is equilateral" (the $60^\circ$ thing is redundant) and that the triangles share vertex $A$, there's no way to determine the scale factor. Where are points $D$ and $E$?

Comment: Give me a minute- I'll put up the figure.

Comment: Hint: Suppose $DC$ has length $x$. Then what's $|AC|$? and $|AD|$? And what can you do from there?

Comment: AC would be $2x$ then.

Comment: And AD would be $(3x^2)^\frac{1}{2}$ via Pythagorean Theorem, if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: You're doing it correctly!  (Note that you can write $|AD|$ as $3^{1/2} \; x$.) Now, since $AD$ and $AB$ are corresponding sides of the two equilateral triangles $\triangle ADE$ and $\triangle ABC$, what's the ratio you're after?

Comment: Would I be right in saying that the ratio between the lengths of the triangles: 

ABC $:$ AED $= 2:3^\frac{1}{2}= 1:\frac{3^\frac{1}{2}}{2}$

Comment: You would be right! I might leave the ratio as $2: 3^{1/2}$ (or $2:\sqrt{3}$) to avoid fractions (and to make it easier to determine the ratio of areas), or write the other version as $1 : \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$. But that's really just style over substance.

Comment: @ Blue, thank you for your help.

If you want to put some of your comments as tips or an answer below, I'll be happy to award it best answer.

Comment: You did all the work. Write your steps as an answer and award yourself. :)  I'll be happy to upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If side $DC$$ = $ $x$, then $AC$ must be $2x$ because both triangles are equilateral. By Pythagorean theorem, $AD$ is $3^\frac{1}{2}x$. Then $AD:AC=3^\frac{1}{2}:2=\frac{3^\frac{1}{2}{}}{2}:1$. So the scale factor $k$, is $\frac{3^\frac{1}{2}}{2}$. Using the formula:

$\frac{\text{Area of }AED}{\text{Area of }ABC}=k^2$

$\frac{\text{Area of }AED}{\text{Area of }ABC}=(\frac{3^\frac{1}{2}}{2})^2$

$\frac{\text{Area of }AED}{\text{Area of }ABC}=\frac{3}{4}$

Therefore $k^2= \frac{3}{4}$ and so the ratio between triangle $ADE$ and $ABC$ is $1:\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: (+1) I'd have written the answer as $4:3$, personally, but that's just a matter of taste.